# libcoi_device.so.0 Not found Compiling Error with Intel 19.0.4 OpenMP 5.0 Offloading

Tags: c++, c, openmp, intel, offloading

I just installed Intel® Parallel Studio XE Cluster Edition for Linux*
2019 and am trying to use OpenMP to offload to a Xeon Phi accelerator. I am using cmake, with flags

```
CC=~/intel/bin/icc CXX=~/intel/bin/icpc CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-qopenmp-offload" cmake ..
```

This sets everything up without any issues. However, when I run make I get the following error:

```
ld: warning: libcoi_device.so.0, needed by /opt/software/icc/2018.1.163-GCC-6.4.0-2.28/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libioffload_target.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/software/icc/2018.1.163-GCC-6.4.0-2.28/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libioffload_target.so.5: undefined reference to `COIPerfGetCycleFrequency@COI_1.0'
/opt/software/icc/2018.1.163-GCC-6.4.0-2.28/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libioffload_target.so.5: undefined reference to `COIBufferAddRef@COI_1.0'
/opt/software/icc/2018.1.163-GCC-6.4.0-2.28/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libioffload_target.so.5: undefined reference to `COIPipelineStartExecutingRunFunctions@COI_1.0'
/opt/software/icc/2018.1.163-GCC-6.4.0-2.28/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libioffload_target.so.5: undefined reference to `COIEngineGetIndex@COI_1.0'
/opt/software/icc/2018.1.163-GCC-6.4.0-2.28/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libioffload_target.so.5: undefined reference to `COIBufferReleaseRef@COI_1.0'
/opt/software/icc/2018.1.163-GCC-6.4.0-2.28/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libioffload_target.so.5: undefined reference to `COIProcessWaitForShutdown@COI_1.0'
make[2]: *** [GPU] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/GPU.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Upon further inspection I found that in both the /opt and ~/intel installs of the intel compiler `libioffload_target.so.5` is missing `libcoi_device.so.0 => not found`.

Any ideas on why this might be?

Comment: Did you find the solution to it?

Comment: I did not. I ended up using an IBM compiler instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your terminal output gives a possible solution.

> ld: warning: libcoi_device.so.0, needed by /opt/software/icc/2018.1.163-GCC-6.4.0-2.28/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libioffload_target.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)